# substitute certain characters in strings found in an object

Tags: json, jq

I have a list of objects and want to replace all occurrences of `.` with `:` when the key is `Name` using `jq`

input:

```
{
  "Parameters": [
    {
      "Name": "TEST.AB.SOMETHING",
      "Value": "hvfuycsgvfiwbiwbibibewfiwbcfwifcbwibcibc"
    },
    {
      "Name": "TEST_GF_USER",
      "Value": "ssssecret"
    }
  ]
}
```

expected output:

```
{
  "Parameters": [
    {
      "Name": "TEST:AB:SOMETHING",
      "Value": "hvfuycsgvfiwbiwbibibewfiwbcfwifcbwibcibc"
    },
    {
      "Name": "TEST_GF_USER",
      "Value": "ssssecret"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may split by `.` and join by `:`

```
jq '(.Parameters[].Name)|=(split(".")|join(":"))' file.json
```

The assignment is done using the [*update* operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Assignment).

Answer (score 7):

The trick is to use `.Name |= gsub("\\.";":")`.  In your case (a flat list), it's simple.  If you want to modify the keys of all objects in an arbitrary JSON text, the simplest would be to use `walk/1`:

```
walk( if type == "object" and (.Name|type) == "string" then .Name |= gsub("\\.";":")) else . end )
```

(If your jq does not have walk/1, then its jq definition can readily be found by googling.)

Comment: Thanks. for the answer.