# Replace spaces with plus signs in string using jq

Tags: jq

Let's say I have the following phrase:

```
Tiger Woods plays golf
```

I'm trying to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to replace all of the spaces with `+` signs so the final result would be:

```
Tiger+Woods+plays+golf
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355182/substitute-certain-characters-in-strings-found-in-an-object

Comment: JohnnyMetz - Please adhere to the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a string `"Tiger Woods plays golf"`

using jq's expression `gsub("\\s";"+")` - you should be able to replace those spaces by "+" characters

result[1]: `"Tiger+Woods+plays+golf"`

[1] https://jqplay.org/s/SxiKIClW13